# Using Scheduler, how to ensure file is only run by Heroku server?

Tags: php, heroku, cron, scheduled-tasks

I want to run a php file with Heroku Scheduler. What are some methods to ensure that not just anyone can come along and execute the file? Is there a way to put stuff above the web root ('www' with a php app)?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to use a `.htaccess` file in your project's root directory to ensure that these files are not accessible through Apache.  Scheduler will still be able to execute them.

```
<Directory /app/www/DIRECTORY_NAME>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
</Directory>
```

With `DIRECTORY_NAME` being the name you've put these PHP files in.

Comment: And the .htaccess goes in /www/ or /www/MY_DIR? Thanks!